# NSUserDefaults in Mac Application

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have a couple of questions about NSUserDefaults in Mac OS X:

1. When does the `NSUserDefaults` use the dictionary provided by `registerDefaults`? Only the first time the application is opened or every time the application is opened?
2. Where is the information from `NSUserDefaults` stored?
3. How can I reset some value stored in `NSUSerDefaults`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Luckily Apple provides documentation for Cocoa programming!

You can check the [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and
**[Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)** for solid information on how to use the OS X preferences system from a Cocoa app.

Answer (score 0):

2: The file will in your preferences folder:

> ~/Library/Preferences/yourname.yourapp.plist

You can easily keep an eye on it in the Finder preview pane, which saves having to load it.